# postgresql & json - counting distinct values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have a table that looks like,

```
| id | json                            |
| -- | ------------------------------- |
| 1  | {"id":1,"customer":"BANK"}      |
| 1  | {"id":1,"customer":"BANK"}      |
| 2  | {"id":2,"customer":"GOVT"}      |
| 3  | {"id":3,"customer":"BANK"}      |
| 4  | {"id":4,"customer":"ASSET MGR"} |
| 4  | {"id":4,"customer":"ASSET MGR"} |
```

I need the output of counting the occurrences of customers with unique ids, such as

```
| customer    | count |
| ----------- | ----- |
| "BANK"      | 2     |
| "GOVT"      | 1     |
| "ASSET MGR" | 1     |
```

Is there a good way to achieve using PostgreSQL & json? I currently am able to extract the customer and IDs, but am having difficulty counting the unique json objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> select count(distinct id), jsondata ->> 'customer' customer 
> from data
> group by customer
> ```
>
> ```
> count | customer 
> ----: | :--------
>     1 | ASSET MGR
>     2 | BANK     
>     1 | GOVT
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=acc03a8100cbb41209047236eb612a08)*